# Android app security test failed! ... Saying, component is not Protected. An intent-filter exists

Tags: android, security, intentfilter

There is security issue reported from our client about some of the Activity and BroadcastReceiver.

The security test result was talking about

```
(com.****.*****.Activity / BroadcastReceiver) is
not Protected.
An intent-filter exists.
```

> Thing which is common is that all contains  intent-filter

Please suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set android:exported="false" for the activity in your [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> **android:exported** :
>   This element sets whether the activity can be
>   launched by components of other applications — "true" if it can be,
>   and "false" if not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by
>   components of the same application or applications with the same user
>   ID. If you are using intent filters, you should not set this element
>   "false". If you do so, and an app tries to call the activity, system
>   throws an ActivityNotFoundException. Instead, you should prevent other
>   apps from calling the activity by not setting intent filters for it.
>
> If you do not have intent filters, the default value for this element
>   is "false". If you set the element "true", the activity is accessible
>   to any app that knows its exact class name, but does not resolve when
>   the system tries to match an implicit intent.
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to
>   other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the
>   external entities that can invoke the activity (see the permission
>   attribute).

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.YourActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
```

You can do same for BroadcastReceiver.